# Differentiability of $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^3\sin\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> (x^{2}+y^{2})^{3}\sin\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
> 0 & x=y=0
> \end{cases}$. Find maximal r s.t
>
> a. all derivatives of order r exist
>
> b.all derivatives of order r exist and continuous

For $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ f is product of differentiable functions so I checked only in $(0,0)$ getting $df(0,0)\equiv0$ and the partial derivatives are:$$\frac{\partial f_{3}}{\partial x}=6x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}-2x(x^{2}+y^{2})\cdot\cos(\frac{1}{^{x^{2}+y^{2}}}) \\ \frac{\partial f_{3}}{\partial y}=6y\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}-2y(x^{2}+y^{2})\cdot\cos(\frac{1}{^{x^{2}+y^{2}}})$$. for $x(,y)\neq 0$ and both equal 0 for $(0,0)$. both derivatives are continious. Then I found also the second differential is defined (in 0 $d^2f\equiv0$ again) and the partial derivatives are: $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial x}=6(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)-2(x^{2}+y^{2})\cos\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-16x^{2}\cos\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}+24x^{2}\sin\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-\frac{4x^{2}\sin\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\ \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial y}=6(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)-2(x^{2}+y^{2})\cos\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-16y^{2}\cos\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}+24y^{2}\sin\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-\frac{4y^{2}\sin\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}=24xy(x^{2}+y^{2})\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)-16xy\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)-\frac{4xy\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$. again $\forall (x,y)\neq (0,0)$ the derivatives are continuous and differentaible. I want to check differentiablity in $(0,0)$ i.e $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial x}(h,h)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial x}(0,0)+L(h)+\epsilon(h)\cdot ||h||$$. I took $L(h)=0$ so now I need to prove $\lim\frac{\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x\partial x}}{\mathcal{O}(h)}=0$. taking absolute value $$0\le\mid \frac{\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x\partial x}}{\mathcal{O}(h)}\mid\le 6(x^{2}+y^{2})^{1.5}-2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}+\frac{8x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}-\frac{4x^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{1.5}}$$. I want to take $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ on each side and by sandwitch theorm to prove the limit exist but Im not sure that $\frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^1.5}\to 0$ when $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. how can I prove it does tend to 0? if im wrong, how can I (dis)prove the differential doesn't exist?

Comment: **Hint**: try to approach the origin along some linear path. What do you get? Now, how does this affect (a) and (b)?

Comment: Im not sure I understood what did you mean? taking limit in $(x,ax)$ in comparison to $(x,0)$?

Comment: Use polar coordinates...getting $\rho^6\sin\frac{1}{\rho^2}$ and compute the limit

Comment: @CoarguAliquis you could take Avitus's suggestion. Just to clarify my own, the limit you weren't sure about could be handled by examining the restriction to a line through the origin. $(x,x)$ or $(x,0)$ are the simplest cases for my taste, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: how can I use polar cordinates? some of my coefficients are powers of only x. what can I do with them ? convert to $\cos \rho$?

Comment: @JonathanY. so the third differential does not exist at all?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis I suspect Avitus intended to convert the original function to polar coordinates and take it from there. W.r.t. your latest question, if the 2nd derivatives aren't continuous at the origin, what does that say about the differentiability of $D^2f$ there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously $f$ is of class $C^\infty$ on $U=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. It is therefore enough to see what's happining at $(0,0)$.

For every $(x,y) \in U$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)&=&6x(x^2+y^2)^2\sin\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-2x(x^2+y^2)\cos\frac{1}{x^2+y^2},\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)&=&6y(x^2+y^2)^2\sin\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-2y(x^2+y^2)\cos\frac{1}{x^2+y^2},\\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(x,y)&=&\left[6(x^2+y^2)^2+4x^2(x^2+y^2)-\frac{4x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right]\sin\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-2(9x^2+y^2)\cos\frac{1}{x^2+y^2},\\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}(x,y)&=&\left[6(x^2+y^2)^2+4y^2(x^2+y^2)-\frac{4y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right]\sin\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-2(x^2+9y^2)\cos\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)&=&4xy\left[6(x^2+y^2)-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right]\sin\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-16xy\cos\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}.
\end{eqnarray}
Since $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for every $(x,y) \in U$, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}x^5\sin\frac{1}{x^2}=0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y),
$$
i.e. both $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$ are continuous at $(0,0)$.

On the one hand we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)}{x}&=&0=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(0,0),\\
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,y)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)}{y}&=&0=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}(0,0),\\
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)}{y}&=&0=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0),\\
\end{eqnarray}
and by symmetry we also have $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)=0.$

On the other hand, if we set
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac\pi2+2n\pi}} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N},
$$
then $\lim_na_n=0$, but
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_n\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(a_n,0)&=&\lim_n\left[(10a_n^4-4)\sin\frac{1}{a_n^2}-18a_n^2\cos\frac{1}{a_n^2}\right]=-4 \ne 0= \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(0,0),\\
\lim_n\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}(0,a_n)&=&\lim_n\left[(10a_n^4-4)\sin\frac{1}{a_n^2}-18a_n^2\cos\frac{1}{a_n^2}\right]=-4 \ne 0= \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}(0,0),
\end{eqnarray}
i.e. both $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}$ are not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Finally, notice that
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_n\frac{\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(a_n,0)-\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(0,0)}{a_n}&=&\lim_n\left(10a_n^3-\frac{4}{a_n}\right)=-\infty.
\end{eqnarray}
As a conclusion, the partial derivatives of $f$ exist up the 2nd order, and only those of first order are continuous.